# Android - получить лог своего приложения

Tags: android, java, логирование

Приветствую! В течении работы моё приложение заносит информацию в LogCat в разные группы - debug, error, what a terrible failure. К концу работы приложения (в onDestroy) хотелось бы как-нибудь достать (в виде строки) записанные приложением логи. Как это можно сделать без сторонних библиотек и без применения рут-прав?

В гугле был, ничего дельного кроме Acra не заметил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[попробуй это](http://forum.startandroid.ru/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=1781) Решение обобщенное, но немного допилишь напильником и получится то что надо.